# Producer error Kafka Quickstart on Mac OS X

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I keep getting an annoying intermittent **Publisher** problem whilst trying to follow the [Kafka Quickstart](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) - Kafka 1.0.0

Zookeeper starts fine     - `binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181`

Kafka broker starts fine      - `Awaiting socket connections on 0.0.0.0:9092`

Successfully create topic `test`

#### Config.

The interesting bits of config in`server.properties`

```
broker.id=0
...
port = 9092
advertised.host.name = localhost
...
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
```

#### Producer Error

But when I try and publish some messages to `test` with a Producer, I get the following error.

```
$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
>message 1
// then it seems to hang

[2018-02-20 14:34:50,145] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 2 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms
```

The annoying thing is that this was working 1 day ago and now I get this producer error even after no change to config.

Anyone seen this error and know how to fix it maybe?

#### NOTE: Shutdown is always unclean

Note: When I shutdown Kafka broker it never does so cleanly - Im not sure if this is related to the same issue I am having.

```
[2018-02-20 14:54:32,774] WARN [KafkaServer id=0] Error during controlled shutdown, possibly because leader movement took longer than the configured controller.socket.timeout.ms and/or request.timeout.ms: Connection to localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) failed. (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2018-02-20 14:54:37,783] WARN [KafkaServer id=0] Proceeding to do an unclean shutdown as all the controlled shutdown attempts failed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2018-02-20 14:54:37,785] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Shutting down (kafka.network.SocketServer)
```

Comment: Is there anything relevant in the Kafka server log around the time of the error you're getting?

Comment: Do you have anything like VirtualBox running? I've had problems in the past with various network settings mucking things up that had previously worked just fine.

Comment: No activity at all written to the broker log. I don't have Virtual Box installed actually - Ive only had the machine for a few days so it is relatively clean.

Comment: Could you please try and:
1. run broker-list command
2. kafka-topics describe command
3. check the kafka service logs
and share the output/results/observations?
We may find some reasons for this behaviour there.

Comment: We are also facing such problems in our production deployment. One of our servers running producer start showing these logs when others can push data fine.